# Need help finding the compose button in Gmail using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am having trouble with finding the compose button in Gmail. Every time I run it I get the following error message saying that the element doesn't exist

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class="T-I T-I-KE L3"]"}`

I have tried multiple things including:

`ComposeButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@jscontroller="eIu7Db"]')`

`ComposeButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="T-I T-I-KE L3"]')`

`ComposeButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@jsaction="click:dlrqf; clickmod:dlrqf"]')`

They have all returned with the same error message

How do I access the compose button?

The greyed out part of the HTML in the linked image is for the compose button

Comment: Try the xpath : "//div[@role='button'][text()='Compose']"

Comment: Have you tried time.sleep(5) before using driver.find_element()? Sometimes the compose window takes a few seconds to load in gmail.

Comment: @art_architect I tried but I still get the same no such element error. Also, I do have the program sleep before I run the find element

Comment: Are you running your driver as headless or are you able to see the browser window as your script is running? Have you been able to visually confirm that in your script you successfully log into gmail and the compose button is loaded at the point you call find_element()?

Comment: I can see the window and it is fully logged into gmail when find_element() is called

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='aic']/div/div")
```

Comment: It still didn't work. I think the issue is my program can't get the HTML of the webpage for some reason or something.

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[gh='cm']").click()
```

(N.B = change the word driver as per your code)